# Why does "pip install" raise a SyntaxError in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install a python package through pip, which raises a SyntaxError within setup.py:

```
$ /usr/bin/pip install dash --user
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting dash
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/94/c591c1ff695c32e7fc5138525f3a792d289160008f1a7f517860cc744a85/dash-0.26.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ysGuJO/dash/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        exec(open('dash/version.py').read(), main_ns)  # pylint: disable=exec-used
      File "<string>", line 1
        __version__ = '0.26.5'
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ysGuJO/dash/
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I suppose it has something todo with a too old python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

since the response is similar to [this, more specific question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131953/syntaxerror-in-setup-py-with-pip-to-install-module) and

```
pip install urllib3
```

worked fine, which only requires >= Python 2.6.

Comment: I think you should upgrade both Python and pip. Python 2 is _old_: its support ends very soon, and everybody's using Python 3 nowadays, so don't miss out on its new features and stuff.

Comment: I am not the system administrator, but thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem because of an older version of python. you might have to upgrade your python. After upgrading you won't be facing any issue.below are the step to upgrade. write the steps in your terminal.

```
    # refreshing the repositories
    sudo apt update
    # its wise to keep the system up to date!
    # you can skip the following line if you not
    # want to update all your software
    sudo apt upgrade
    # installing python 2.7 and pip for it
    sudo apt install python2.7 python-pip
    # installing python-pip for 3.6
    sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python python-pip
python -m pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools==20.7.0
python -m pip install xxx
```