# unable to install scrapy using pip on my windows 10 64 bit

Tags: python, installation, pip, scrapy

This is what i get on cmd when i tried to pip install scrapy...i could'nt put the full code in due to char limits. This is on a windows 10 64 bit pc..kindly help. please help me deal with this problem...cant find any answers that work for me..kindly show steps as i'm new to the python universe..will appreciate the help

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip install scrapy
Collecting scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.1.3 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: itemadapter>=0.1.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.5.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (2.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib>=1.4.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity>=16.0.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protego>=0.1.15 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (0.1.16)
Collecting Twisted>=17.9.0
  Using cached Twisted-20.3.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.5.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.1.3->scrapy) (47.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from w3lib>=1.17.0->scrapy) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=16.0.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest!=1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (2.9)
Using legacy setup.py install for Twisted, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: Twisted, scrapy
    **Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_mynyc6t\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_mynyc6t\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-798owh4i\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\Twisted'
         cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_mynyc6t\Twisted\
    Complete output (955 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Daniel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131953/syntaxerror-in-setup-py-with-pip-to-install-module), turtle already comes included with python so you don't need to install it.

Comment: ok thanks. i tried to install scrapy,,

Comment: i get an error while downloading scrapy...its a big one

Comment: This is how it goes    ....                                                                                      
    Installing collected packages: Twisted, scrapy
    Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vrq8cue7\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-

Comment: also i have tried installing twisted using links on stack but just not working out...really stuck with this

Comment: tried installing pyautogui and it worked that means there are some dependencies with scrapy i"m not able to get...i guess. please help

Comment: Scrapy is built on top of the Twisted asynchronous networking library so you need to install Twisted first.
Make sure you have a look at [this page](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) and install all the necessary packages.